# lld-link error under VS 2022 "...\vcpkg\installed\\x64-windows\debug\lib\*.lib': invalid argument"

Tags: c++, clang++

I'm attempting to build a smallish windows DLL (which builds properly using visual studio compiler) using clang 14. The program uses Boost 1.80.0 (successfully compiled boost libs using clang), and g3log (libs were compiled using VS compiler)
After a bit of tweaking, the program source files all compile, but will not link, giving the error:

```
"lld-link : error : could not open 'D:\dev\github\vcpkg\installed\\x64-windows\debug\lib\*.lib': invalid argument"
```

the link flags are :

```
/OUT:"c:\dev\testproj\x64\Debug\test01.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"c:\dev\testproj\x64\Debug\test01.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "g3log.lib" "Ws2_32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"c:\dev\testproj\x64\Debug\test01.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"c:\dev\testproj\x64\Debug\test01.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\test01.dll.intermediate.manifest" /LIBPATH:"c:\dev\testproj\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\third-party\boost\1.80.0\bin" /LIBPATH:"c:\dev\testproj\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\third-party\g3log\1.3.4_dbug\build\Debug\" /LIBPATH:"..\windows\test01\x64\Debug\"
```

I'm unclear where this error is originating, any ideas on what is going on?

{EDIT}  a search for "vcpkg" in the project files came up empty

Comment: `'D:\dev\github\vcpkg\installed\\x64-windows\debug\lib\*.lib'` is an invalid argument. You will have to figure out how that got in your Visual Studio Community 2022 project file.

Comment: @drescherjm VS uses a glob to link all libraries installed in vcpkg. Its own compiler handles it, but lld doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I am used to using CMake for my Visual Studio usage.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed by setting:

Configuration Properties->vcpkg->General->User Vcpkg   to No

Answer (score 1):

Under the `vcpkg` properties disable the option called "Use AutoLink". There's a note in the description of the option that states it explicitly does not work with `lld-link.exe` meaning you'll have to link manually.